# I can't find the error causing a null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-launcher

I am new to android programming and I am trying to create a simple home screen replacement/launcher using a viewpager.

When I try to run the application, it starts up and then immediately force closes. I think it is something to do with a null pointer exception but I am really new to programming and can't find the source of the error.

This is my logcat.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dntmdp.matthewhuckel.simplephonelauncher/com.dntmdp.matthewhuckel.simplephonelauncher.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            // etc...
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.dntmdp.matthewhuckel.simplephonelauncher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            // etc...
08-13 20:10:58.585    1805-1805/com.dntmdp.matthewhuckel.simplephonelauncher I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1805 SIG: 9
```

This is my main activity java class.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button phone;
    // more buttons

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton phone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // Exception thrown on this line
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.phone");
                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

       //setting more onclicklisteners in exactly the same manner

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_layout);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    // menu initialization
}
```

Comment: which line is line 47 in your activity?

Comment: Your layout set with `setContentView()` doesn't have the views you're trying to `findViewById()`.

Comment: Which line is 47 in your `MainActivity.java` ?

Comment: The phone.setOnClickListenser is line 47.

Comment: If the code is an exact copy from the code, line 47 is `phone.setOnClickListener`: `activity_main.xml` doesnt contain a definition for `R.id.imageButton`

Comment: pls post your layout xml

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was trying to find the image button id's in the activity_main xml, but they were in other activities.